# Android app crashing because of imageview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity, which has 5 Fragments in a ViewPager.  When i run the app, it crashes due to an Inflate Exception:

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59: Binary XML file line #59: Error inflating class

If i take out my ImageViews it won't crash.  What i don't understand is that there are only 5 images (one in each Fragment) and each one is only 60kb or less.  How can these ImageViews cause the XML to error on inflating?  It doesn't make sense!

Also, the problem seems to happen only on some versions of Android.  The app will run on my Note 3 but not on a new S6 Edge, which has more memory. I don't understand why this is happening!

Can any one explain this?

Here is the XML that is trying to be inflated when the app crashes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ivSplashFive"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/splashbeach2" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_above="@+id/llAccept">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="30dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="SEE WHAT&apos;S GOING ON"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="ANYWHERE IN THE WORLD"
                    android:id="@+id/textView69"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView50"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_white"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llAccept"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/llAccept"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/llSignIn"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:gravity="right">


                <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                    android:id="@+id/login_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_fb"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Terms &amp; Conditions"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Privacy Statement"
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/llLoggingIn"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView94"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/splashbeachlogo"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress2"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView85"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="67dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout25"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView85"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"></LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Welcome To DropMap"
                android:id="@+id/textView168"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="We are setting things up for you\nOne Moment Please"
                android:id="@+id/textView169"
                android:textColor="#ddd"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Stacktrace is:

```
01-02 22:17:40.609 2590-2590/au.appsprout.com.dropmap W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 61440012 byte allocation with 3329648 free bytes and 3MB until OOM"
01-02 22:17:40.610 2590-2590/au.appsprout.com.dropmap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: au.appsprout.com.dropmap, PID: 2590
                                                                        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                            at au.appsprout.com.dropmap.Splash$Fragment3.onCreateView(Splash.java:208)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                            at android.v
```

Comment: what is the error message? out of memory ? NPE ? if out of memory then try resizing your images and compressing them.

Comment: @Nickmccomb Please point out which image is causing crash, and provide full stack trace

Comment: Hi R4j, If i leave any ImageView in the layout then it gives the same error (i have edited my question with the stack trace)

Virus, it is an out of memory error but the images are optimised (they are only 50kb each), and it works on phones with less memory, like a JellyBean Note 3, but doesn't work on Marshmellow S6 Edge.. Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I also have android:largeHeap="true" in my Manifest file

Comment: Check your image dimensions. If it too large, resize it. I have some image with demension 3000 x 1500, but just large 10kb

Answer (score 0):

use Picasso library 
[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(R.drawable.splashbeach2)
.resize(50, 50)
.centerCrop()
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: Hi Meysam, i will try Picasso later on today and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Using Picasso didn't fix the problem, it looks like Picasso only loads images if there is memory, whereas without Picasso the app will crash if there is no memory.  How can two images that are only 40kb each cause an app to have an Out Of Memory error???  It doesn't make sense.  Other apps have heaps of images and don't crash!